# Conformal mapping of Euclidean Schwarzschild AdS black hole

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, conformal-field-theory, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I have been trying to understand this for some time. given the Euclidean S-AdS black hole metric,

$$ ds^2 = f(r)d\tau^2 + \frac{1}{f(r)} dr^2 + r^2d\Omega^{2}_{D-2} $$

From what I understand this has the structure of $R^{2}$ and $S^{D-2}$. and $R^2$ can be mapped to a circle on the complex plane where we end up wit the "Cigar diagram(?)" My question is how do we end up there so for example if we only had $ds^2=d\tau^2+dx^2$ how do we map this into a circle?

Comment: See section 5.2 of https://laces.web.cern.ch/LACES19/BlackHoleLectures_LACES2019_online.pdf . Here Cassini recognizes $d\rho^2+\frac{\rho^2}{4r_s}d\tau$ as the metric of a disk (which ought to be of the form $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2$)